# Styles do not work after converting from erb to slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I translated the erb file into slim and as a result, instead of the pictures in the window, the address on them began to be displayed, how can I fix it?

```
.col-xs-12.right-content-block
  .faces.slider-team-slick-js
    - @development.each do |developer|
      .col-xs-4
        .flex-item.animated.fadeInDown.rectangle-and-text-hover.img-face
          | , style='background-image: url(#{image_path(developer.image_url)});' &gt;
              .text
                p.name= developer.name
                   .horizontal-line
                    p.specialization= developer.title
```

There should be a picture in place of the text.

[image]

Update.

I helped this here.

```
.col-xs-12.right-content-block
  .faces.slider-team-slick-js
    - @development.each do |developer|
      .col-xs-4
        .flex-item.animated.fadeInDown.rectangle-and-text-hover.img-face style="background-image: url(#{image_path(developer.image_url)})" 
          .text 
            p.name = developer.name
            .horizontal-line
            p.specialization= developer.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `''` by `""`

Then you type these lines:

```
.col-xs-12.right-content-block
  .faces.slider-team-slick-js
    - @development.each do |developer|
      .col-xs-4
        .flex-item.animated.fadeInDown.rectangle-and-text-hover.img-face style="background-image: url(#{image_path(developer.image_url)});"&gt;
          .text
            p.name = developer.name
              .horizontal-line
              p.specialization= developer.title
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but your answer did not help me.